# $N-$Green function in $\mathbb R^N$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations

Let $N \geq 3$. Does there exist solution of the following equation
$$-\Delta_N G + G^{N-1} = \delta_0,$$
where $-\Delta_N = - \text{ div}(|\nabla \cdot |^{N-2} \nabla \cdot )$ denotes $N-$Laplace operator and $\delta_0$ denotes Diract measure at $0$?

Could someone give me an answer or references to this question? Thank!

Comment: On the way to upvoting this interesting question, I'm reminded an upvote means "this question shows research effort, it is interesting and clear". It is certainly clear. But why didn't you include (a derivation of) the equation satisfied by a solution of the form $G(x)=g(|x|)$ ?? Isn't it an obvious first step towards a solution?

Comment: Then, did you observe $G(x)=a\log|x|+b$ satisfies $\Delta_N G=c\delta_0$ ?